# Specify which argument is supplied by X in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I've got a function, e.g. `fun(a, b = 1, c = 3, ...)`, that takes a number of arguments, some of which have default values. I would like to call this function using `lapply(X, FUN, ...)`, but specify explicitly which argument I would like `X` to supply. In the example above, the `X` vector could be supplied for `a` or `b` or `c`, or `xyz` in the `...`.

Normally I might call `lapply(1:5, fun, a = 4)` and I imagine it would use `1:5` as the `b` argument.

- Is there a way to make that more explicit?
- What if I want to use the default argument for `b` and use `1:5` for `c`?
- What if I want to use `1:5` as an `xyz` argument in the `...`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: The general syntax should work  `lapply(1:5,function(x,a=4,..,) {  } )`

Comment: Why would you _want_ to pass other variables to the function?  `lapply` itself will only give you a single entry from the list on which it is operating.

Comment: It assigns to the first otherwise unassigned parameter. If you want to be super-clear–or the parameter you want to assign to is not the next one–just wrap the call in an anonymous function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Normally I might call `lapply(1:5, fun, a = 4)` and I imagine it would use 1:5 as the b argument.

Yes, your imagination is correct. `lapply` uses positional matching to pass its `X` parameter to the function. Normal [rules of argument matching](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching) apply, which means exact matching of named parameters takes precedence.

An alternative would of course be to wrap `fun` in an anonymous function:

```
lapply(1:5, function(b, a, ...) fun(a = a, b = b, ...), a = 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle you use case would be to simply call your own function inside the custom function which `lapply` exposes to you:

```
lst <- list(v1=c(1:3), v2="Hello", v3=5)

result <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
                         y <- FUN(x, a, b, c, ...)   # Here FUN() is your own function
                         return(y)
                      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapply` to specify static and dynamic arguments explicitly:

```
mapply(cbind, a = "a constant", b = 1:5, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```